# Copy selected values from table and paste into div onclick - javascript

Tags: javascript, copy

Ive got a table of data and on each row the there is a button, onclick im trying to 'copy' that rows data, and 'paste' it into another div.

Here's my HTML:

```
<table class="list">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Number</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Alpha</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>
            <button id="addValues">Add</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Beta</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>
            <button id="addValues">Add</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Charlie</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>
            <button id="addValues">Add</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Delta</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>
            <button id="addValues">Add</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="selection">
    <h4>Selections</h4>

    <!-- SELECTED VALUES  -->
</div>
```

Ive been trying to do this using:

```
$(function()  {
    $('addValues').click(function(){
        var content = $('tr').html();
        var newdiv = $("#selection");
        newdiv.html(content);
        $('#content').after(newdiv);
    });
  });
```

But cant quite get it to work, any ideas ?

Ive made a fiddle of the problem here - http://jsfiddle.net/9sZaX/2/

Comment: Don't use duplicate `id` attributes. Give the `<button>`s a `class` attribute, like "addValues", and use this selector: `$(".addValues")`

Comment: Also, try setting the jsFiddle to actually use jQuery. Here's a fiddle with these 2 changes: http://jsfiddle.net/RPd3v/ . Doesn't fix it completely, but it's a start

Comment: And here's a fiddle effectively "copying" the row's content to the target div: http://jsfiddle.net/RPd3v/2/

Comment: Another important problem was the fact that there is no element with the id `content` on the page, so the `.after()` wasn't really doing anything

Comment: @ian thanks very much, my js i extremely rusty if you put that as an answer ill mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your jsFiddle and/or code.

Don't use duplicate `id` attributes. It will cause unexpected results because jQuery will only select the first one found (which is expected, since there should only be one element with that `id`). Instead, give the `<button>`s a `class` attribute, like "addValues", and use this selector: `$(".addValues")`.

Also, try setting the jsFiddle to actually use `jQuery` (set up on the left side of the page).

Another important problem was the fact that there is no element with the `id` of "content" on the page, so the `.after()` wasn't really doing anything.

Here's how I would set it up, depending on your actual requirements:

HTML -

```
<table class="list">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Number</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Alpha</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td><button class="addValues">Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Beta</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td><button class="addValues">Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Charlie</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td><button class="addValues">Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Delta</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td><button class="addValues">Add</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="selection">
    <h4>Selections</h4>
    <!-- SELECTED VALUES  -->
</div>
```

JS -

```
$(function () {
    $(".addValues").click(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            myCol = $this.closest("td"),
            myRow = myCol.closest("tr"),
            targetArea = $("#selection");
        targetArea.append(myRow.children().not(myCol).text() + "<br />");
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/RPd3v/2/

Comment: Can you provide a workaround to create the **new table** in the **selection** div with column name as well as also a gap between columns?